# 3D surface plot with color to represent 4th dimension

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, 3d

I have a function in which output 'w' depends upon three variables as shown below:

```
w = x^2 * (3 + 2*x)(1+x*y)(1+x*z)/(1+x^2)
```

x, y and z can take on any value from 0 to for example 2

I want to be able to draw a 3D surface with x,y,z as coordinates and w to be evaluated from above equation and its value to be represented as color of surface. So in effect, it will be giving information in 4 dimensions. Below is a MWE of the code which I am trying to build on but unable to do so far.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    declare function = {
        q(\x) = \x - 1;
        Z(\x,\y) = \x^2 + \y^2 + q(\x);
    }
    ]
    \begin{axis}
    \addplot3 [surf] {Z(x,y)};
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Now the problem is that you don't provided the required argument to `\addplot` where is stated **what** should be plotted.

Comment: Please do not edit questions to include copies of answers. It makes things very confusing and is not at all fair to the people who answered your original question.

Comment: Your current code does not provide any information about the shape of the surface, but only its colour. At least, so it seems to me. If `x`, `y` and `z` can each take any value in the given ranges, then you don't have a surface. You have a cuboid. Or so it seems to me. I don't know anything about it, however.

Answer (score 4):

So you mean something like that?

Then simply also declare your `w` function and use that as `point meta` expression. By adjusting the `point meta min` and `point meta max` values you can play a bit with the "4D effect".

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{
        compat=1.3,
    }
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        declare function = {
            q(\x) = \x - 1;
            Z(\x,\y) = \x^2 + \y^2 + q(\x);
%            % in your provided function the multiplication signs are missing
%            % at the given positions indicated by "v" in the next line
%            %                              v         v
%            w(\x,\y,\z) = \x^2 * (3 + 2*\x) (1+\x*\y) (1+\x*\z)/(1+\x^2);
%            % it seems that is is interpreted as the following line, which
%            % gives the same result
%            w(\x,\y,\z) = (1+\x*\z)/(1+\x^2);
            % adding the multiplication signs yield the "right"/intended result
            w(\x,\y,\z) = \x^2 * (3 + 2*\x)*(1+\x*\y)*(1+\x*\z)/(1+\x^2);
        }
    ]
        \begin{axis}[
            colormap/viridis,
            colorbar,
            % adjust these values to your needs or comment/delete them,
            % to automatically set them to the calculated min and max values
            point meta min=-1e4,
            point meta max=+1e4,
        ]
            \addplot3 [
                surf,
                point meta={w(x,y,z)}
            ] {Z(x,y)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image showing the result]

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer but actually x,y and z are independent variables and do not depend upon each other (not related in anyway). Please suggest keeping that in mind

Comment: x = 1,2,3,...m ; y = 1,2,3,...n ; z = 1,2,3,...o ; w = f(x,y,z)

Comment: ok, to better distinguish the various variables I suggest that we use `w = f(a,b,c)` and use `x`, `y` and `z` for the coordinates in the plot. When `a`, `b` and `c` are all independent and don't relate to `x`, `y` and `z`, from where do you know to which point on the surface which `w` value corresponds? So I guess there *has* to be *some* link of the 6 variables, right?

Comment: It is like this: `w = f(x,y,z) = x^2 * (3 + 2*x)(1+xy)(1+xz)/(1+x^2)` whereas `x=0,1,2,3`, `y=0,1,2,3` and `z=0,1,2,3`. Now we know all the values as well. First we will input all possible values of `x`, `y` and `z` to find a matrix `w` with order `4 x 4 x 4`. So finally, we will need to plot values of `x,y,z` vs `w` with `w` being represented by a change in color by using for example `colorbar` etc. I hope, I could make a question clearer.

Comment: Please see my edited answer where I "corrected" the declaration of function `w` where I added some multiplication signs (see the comments in the code). I think this is exactly what you were asking for. Whatever surface you plot in the 3D plot will show the color of the corresponding calculated `w` value.

Comment: Is it possible to not use the following statements: `q(\x) = \x - 1;` and `Z(\x,\y) = \x^2 + \y^2 + q(\x);`? Because these are not related to my problem in anyway. I mentioned them in question only as an MWE. I would like the `declare fucntion` part to be limited to only `w(\x,\y,\z) = \x^2 * (3 + 2*\x)*(1+\x*\y)*(1+\x*\z)/(1+\x^2);`

Comment: As I already stated: You can plot any function you like with `\addplot`. If you don't state the expression `Z(x,y)` to the command, of course also the corresponding declarations aren't needed.

Comment: I edited my original question to include your code as an MWE. Kindly review it now as it is still giving me an error like: Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, the supplied plot command is unknown or unsupported by pgfplots! Ignoring it.. ];